# tkz-fct: Define function in correct coordinates when axes have non-trivial step size

Tags: tikz-pgf, coordinates, tkz-fct

Consider the following example:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tkz-base}
\usepackage{tkz-fct}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.8]
        \tkzInit[xmax=14.9,ymax=1.1,ystep=0.2,xmin=-0.5,ymin=0]
        \tkzGrid
        \tkzAxeXY[/tkzdrawX/label=$t$ in s,/tkzdrawY/label=$v$ in m/s]
        \draw[color=blue, domain=0:3]   plot (\x,{\x/3});
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

It is supposed to plot the function f(x)=x/3. Obviously, the slope of the graph should come out such that f(3)=1. However, we have f(3)=0,2, because ystep=0.2 rather than 1. So, the coordinates are being calculated in what is directly shown (0.2 is the size of one square), not in what the coordinate system's settings imply. Is there a way to change this behavior other than redefine all functions (say, use 5*\x/3 instead of \x/3 when defining the function)? TeX should do the calculations in actual coordinates, not in "number of squares on the picture", if this is possible.

Comment: In the 'tkz-fct''s documentation, must be used for gnuplot functions and with `\tkzFct[samples=2,domain=0:3]{\x/3}{

Comment: it's not the good tag, 'pgfplots' is not used in your code

Comment: Thanks for your proposal! For some reason, it doesn't show a graph for the function at all, the coordinate system stays empty. What could have gone wrong here?

Comment: After the first compilation, a file <name>.tkzfunct.gnuplot is created. You have to open it with gnuplot then recompile with latex.  (if you read French, it's more complete in the documentation)

Comment: I see, thanks! My French is very limited but I get the idea from your explanation. I'm thinking that just redefining the functions is a more comfortable thing to do compared to extending the compilation command by a gnuplot call...

Comment: I post one answer with {pgfplots', we can also work only with tikz

Comment: With `tkz-fct`, I added a solution that matches the initial request

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `tkz-fct` and `gnuplot`

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tkz-base}
\usepackage{tkz-fct}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.7]
        \tkzInit[xmax=14.9,ymax=1.1,ystep=0.2,xmin=-0.5,ymin=0]
        \tkzGrid
        \tkzAxeXY[/tkzdrawX/label=$t$ in s,/tkzdrawY/label=$v$ in m/s]
        %\draw[color=blue, domain=0:3]   plot (\x,\x/3);
        \tkzFct[blue,samples=2,domain=0:3]{\x/3}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

With `tkz-Fct`, to draw segments, you can also manually define two points with `\tkzDefPoint`

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tkz-base}
\usepackage{tkz-fct}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.7]
        \tkzInit[xmax=14.9,ymax=1.1,ystep=0.2,xmin=-0.5,ymin=0]
        \tkzGrid
        \tkzAxeXY[/tkzdrawX/label=$t$ in s,/tkzdrawY/label=$v$ in m/s]
        %\tkzFct[blue,samples=2,domain=0:3]{\x/3}
        \tkzDefPoint(3,1){A}
        \draw[blue](0,0)--(A);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

With `pgfplots`

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        scale only axis,
        width=12cm,
        height=8cm,
        xmin=0, xmax=14.9,
        ymin=0, ymax=1.1,
        axis x line=bottom,
        axis y line=left,
        grid=both,
        xtick={0,1,...,14},
        %ytick={0,0.2,...,1},%<- uncommnet if necessary
        xlabel={$t$ in s},
        xlabel style={
            at={(xticklabel* cs:1)},
            anchor=north west,
            inner sep=2pt,
        },
        ylabel={$v$ in m/s},
        ylabel style={
            at={(yticklabel* cs:1)},
            rotate=-90,
            anchor=west,
            inner sep=2pt,
        },
    ]
    \addplot [blue]  [domain=0:3,samples=2] {x/3};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That's great, thanks! Could you please point out, which line did the magic and fixed the y axis scale in the second variant?

Comment: try with `height=20cm` and  `height=2cm`,, If the proposed graduations are not suitable, you can fix with `ytick={0,0.1,...,3},`

Comment: with `{0,0.1,...,3}`the graduations stops at 1.1 since ymax=1.1

Comment: The pgfplots code works very well, thanks!